# What did numpy's flatten(0) do?

Tags: python, numpy, flatten, legacy

Python 3.8, Numpy 1.18.1

The code has the line,

`L = H.flatten(0)`

This obvioulsy throws the following error,

> ValueError: Non-string object detected for the array ordering. Please
> pass in 'C', 'F', 'A', or 'K' instead

Now I have changed the line to,

`L = H.flatten('C')`

and the code works fine, unfortunately it also runs fine (but with different results) if I change it to,

`L = H.flatten('F')`

My working assumption is that the original intention was row-major (C-style) as not that many people outside of HPC are using Fortran.

I would like to know for sure though & so far my searches haven't turned up anything.

So, what **did** numpy's flatten(0) do when it was in use?

Comment: Without knowing the source of that code I don't think we can help you.  It could be typo.  Or there could have been a time when `flatten` ignored such a parameter, or interpreted the `0` as the default.  It is compiled code, so the processing of parameters didn't/doesn't always behave like pure Python functions.  So if there was a change, it was most likely API cleaning, not a change in function.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about what is the default order option when flatten() is called?

If so, yes then by default when flatten() is called without any parameter it is equivalently by default calling flatten('C'). You can see it documented over here

https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

the implementation where row-major(C-style) is the default was back in numpy1.8

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.8.0/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.flatten.html#numpy.chararray.flatten

any version before that you have to manually specify if you are flattening row or column in the parameter input.

I don't think there was any elaborate reason as to why flatten('C') is the default. It is just for the sake of simplification.

If it's about why flatten(0) does not work it is simply because flatten does not accept any other inputs beside the options specified 'C', 'F', 'A', 'K' as documented

**EDIT**
Sorry I have misunderstood the question
The numpy.ndarray.flatten() is just an alias for the C PyArray_Flatten which can be found here

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c

Comment: Hi Chass I'm aware of the default settings & also aware that `flatten(0)` does not work (see OP) What I'm asking is what **DID** `flatten(0)` do when it was in use.

Comment: Oh if so then sorry my bad i have misunderstood the question. The numpy.ndarray.flatten() is just an alias for the C PyArray_Flatten which can be found here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c